# Calling ngAfterContentInit in parent class - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I think that `ngAfterViewInit()` should be called after a component's view, and its children's views, are created. I tested this, and found that children's `ngAfterViewInit()`s are called before the parent's `ngAfterViewInit()`. Is it an expected behavior? I need a function in parent class which is called after ngAfterViewInit. How can I do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. `ngAfterViewInit()` is called **after** the view is initialized. Children are part of the view, therefore it can't be called before childrens `ngAfterViewInit()`.

You can try if `ngAfterContentInit()` matches your need, but I'd reconsider your approach. For example use a shared service with an observable to notify the parent about the status of the children.

Comment: I have a 'table' component with nested table-row components and table-col components. After view initialization I would like to build an array in main component. If ngAfterContentInit initializes in parent component first, I am not able to get children content

Comment: Childs initialize first. I find your question confusing. Please add some code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.